# How would i solve this problem and graph it in Mathematica? I am very stuck

Tags: plotting

Use a graph to estimate the coordinates of the rightmost point on the curve, then find the exact coordinates.   $x = t - t^6,\; y = e^t$

Comment: I have tried Plot[{E^x, x - x^6}, {x, -3, 3}] for plotting but i know that it is not the right graph when it comes out.

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot[]`.

Answer (score 2):

For plotting:

```
ParametricPlot[{t - t^6, Exp[t]}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

To find the extremum:

```
NMaximize[t - t^6, t]
{0.582356, {t -> 0.698827}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: For the exact coordinates, either `pt = {t - t^6, Exp[t]} /. t -> ArgMax[t - t^6, t]` or `pt = {t - t^6, Exp[t]} /. Maximize[t - t^6, t][[2]]` which are approximately, `pt//N`, i.e., `{0.582356, 2.01139}`